# Exporting grid view data to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I want to export the data from gridview  to pdf, I have got the error like this while exporting

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

And this is my code

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();  
GridView1.RenderControl(tx);
GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%"); 
GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
```

it was showing error at `Gridview1.RenderConrol(tx)`. `tx` is coming from this statement:

```
HtmlTextWriter tx = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
```

can any one help me

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the control AFTER it was rendered. Could this be what is firing this "RegisterForEventValidation" event?